# Injection order in Opera extensions

Tags: javascript, browser, opera, opera-extension

Suppose I have an extension that has 3 files in `includes` directory:

```
includes/all.js
includes/one.js
includes/two.js
```

`two.js` depends on `one.js` and both of them have 'guard comments':

```
// ==UserScript==
// @include http://*.example.com/*
// @include https://*.example.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
```

`all.js` loads for every page.

**My question is**: in what order those .js files will be processed by Opera on `http://foobar.example.com/` page?

There are some *rumors* that the order is alphabetical, but I cannot find a definitive source of this claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we first shipped user javascript support, I noticed that some users started developing libraries and wanted to control the load / execution order. Some of them assumed the order would be alphabetical (at the time it was random, perhaps by file creation time or some such) and would prefix their library file names with **A-** to make them run first. So I told the developer "let's just implement what people expect and run the scripts in alphabetical order".

It's probably my fault that this is neither documented nor tested..

Answer (score 1):

> There are some rumors that the order is alphabetical, but I cannot
>   find a definitive source of this claim.

Could not find any confirmation in the documentation, but my experiments showed that content scripts are really loaded in alphabetical order.

Comment: If it's not documented anywhere, probably best not to rely upon it.